# ControlTemplate DataGridColumnHeader control visible outside columns

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, controltemplate

I am customizing the style of a DataGrid and I want to describe the ControlTemplate of the header of the columns.

It is basically a TextBlock and an Image but the problem is that when I add the Control Image I find it also in the bottom of my header ...

[image: result image]

I have tried many things to fix the problem like using a DataTemplate instead but it does not work better ...

Here is the XAML code:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
<Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
<Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="0" />
<Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="50" />
<Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource LatoRegular}" />
<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF000000" />
<Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" />
<Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
<Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
            <Grid>
                <Border Grid.Column="0" BorderThickness="0,1,0,1" BorderBrush="#FFEDEDED">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Margin="6" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"
                                FontFamily="{StaticResource LatoRegular}"
                                Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" />

                        <Image Grid.Column="1" Height="16" Width="16" Source="..\..\View\Image\search.png" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality" />
                    </Grid>
                </Border>

                <Thumb x:Name="PART_LeftHeaderGripper" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Opacity="0" Cursor="SizeWE" />
                <Thumb x:Name="PART_RightHeaderGripper" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Opacity="0" Cursor="SizeWE" />
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Do you have an idea to correct or work around the problem please?

Thank you all!

Comment: Give the Style a key and apply on each column as `HeaderStyle="{StaticResource YourColumnHeaderStyle}"`. Does it behave the same?

Comment: Thank you it works better! But on the part where there is no column, the header is the default one.

I can not apply a second controltemplate for this part of the header, an idea?

https://nsa39.casimages.com/img/2018/05/01/180501032920279273.png

Comment: For the last column set the Width="*". It will take the whole space so you don't see any empty header.

Comment: This displays the Image again :(

Answer (score 1):

I succeeded like this:

Without a key for datagrid default style

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="50" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource LatoRegular}" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF000000" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" />
    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                <Border Grid.Column="0" BorderThickness="0,1,0,1" BorderBrush="#FFEDEDED" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

and the style for each column

```
<Style x:Key="styleDtgHeader" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="50" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource LatoRegular}" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF000000" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" />
    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                <Grid>
                    <Border Grid.Column="0" BorderThickness="0,1,0,1" BorderBrush="#FFEDEDED" Background="red">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Margin="6" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                    TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"
                                    FontFamily="{StaticResource LatoRegular}"
                                    Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" />

                            <Image Grid.Column="1" Height="16" Width="16" Source="..\..\View\Image\search.png" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>

                    <Thumb x:Name="PART_LeftHeaderGripper" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Opacity="0" Cursor="SizeWE" />
                    <Thumb x:Name="PART_RightHeaderGripper" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Opacity="0" Cursor="SizeWE" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

But I doubt that this is a clean solution?

Answer (score 1):

You need to do below two things which will solve the issue:

1. Set the width of last column to * so that the extra column will not be created.
2. In your DataGridColumnHeader control template set the Grids first column width to "auto" and the HorizontalAlingment of Image to Left.

Here is the code

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="50" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource LatoRegular}" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF000000" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" />
        <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Border Grid.Column="0" BorderThickness="0,1,0,1" BorderBrush="#FFEDEDED">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Margin="6" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"
                            Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                                <Image Grid.Column="1" Height="16" Width="16" Source="C:\Users\a0711212\Desktop\profilePic.png"
                                      HorizontalAlignment="Left"  RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality" />
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>

                        <Thumb x:Name="PART_LeftHeaderGripper" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Opacity="0" Cursor="SizeWE" />
                        <Thumb x:Name="PART_RightHeaderGripper" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Opacity="0" Cursor="SizeWE" />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: The last column is no longer resizable in this case and I want it to remain so. I also wish that the Image remains frozen right. Thank you all the same :)

Comment: For making the last column resizable you can add a dummy column in the end with MinWidth="0" and Width="0" and Set HeaderStyle={x:null} .